# Tikz Library in Moodle LaTeX

Tags: latex, moodle, tikz

I am currently developing software that creates quizzes in the GIFT format to be uploaded to a Moodle LMS site.

I can easily use LaTeX and input different equations, tables, arrays, etc. but am having some trouble using the tikz library.

I have

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
```

included in my Plugins -> Filters -> TeX Notation settings but when I open questions using tikz drawings they don't show up.

Are there any Moodle gurus that know how to enable these libraries in Moodle or have an alternative method of drawing shapes and labeling the angles and edges for Moodle questions?